# Restrict date range of datelistplot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

How would one clip a `DateListPlot` to a certain date range?

Suppose I have a list of `TimeSeries` that may or may not have values in the range 1980-1981. I can plot all the data using `DateListPlot`, but I would like to display only that part between 1980-1981.

I have tried using `TimeSeriesWindow`, but it throws an error when the `TimeSeries` has no values in the window.

Comment: Wouldn't setting an appropriate `PlotRange` inside the `DateListPlot` do what you want?

Comment: It throws an error for me. I think due to some of the timeseries not having any values in that range.

Comment: Well then time to share your data and code, cause otherwise we are guessing here :-)

Comment: @Ruben what error is being thrown? Does it still give you a plot? Plus, obviously, the code + data you use would be extremely helpful in diagnosing the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a `PlotRange` works for me:

```
DateListPlot[
 {RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[1/3], {0, 50}], 
  RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[1/3], {40, 90}]},
 PlotRange -> {{30, 90}, Automatic}
]
```